# HTML built-in form validation doesn't show error messages when 2 pages in one HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am keeping trying to validate my form. I've used several approaches so far but none of them were working.
My recent trial looks like this (validation of the UK address):

```html
<input 
  class="validation" 
  name="postcode" 
  type="text" 
  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}" 
  oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" 
  placeholder="Enter postcode" 
  required
/>

<script>
  function InvalidMsg(textbox) {

    if (textbox.validity.patternMismatch) {
      textbox.setCustomValidity('please enter 10 numeric value.');
    } else {
      textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

which is based on the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/Sqq8e/5

I also tried something versatile

https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/08/05/html5-form-validation-showing-all-error-messages/

but it didn't work either.

[image]

I think, my situation is very similar to this one:

[Error message not displaying html forms using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457955/error-message-not-displaying-html-forms-using-php)

I can't use the `pattern` attribute only, because it prevents my form from submission

What am I doing wrong here?

I have 2 pages in one HTML file, distincted as per the hint here:

[Multiple distinct pages in one HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211128/multiple-distinct-pages-in-one-html-file)

and the submit button is located on the second page.

As far as I understand it correctly it should return me to the bracket, where the input was wrong and show an error. It doesn't happen.

Comment: Is the text box in a form? Validation is done when you try to submit the form.

Comment: Yes it is, but i have validation button on another side, as I divided this form by 2 pieces. They are on the same HTML site, but you need to press next in order to reach 2nd piece and submit button.

Comment: If you're not submitting the form, you need to call `checkValidity()` or `reportValidity()` to make JavaScript check the constraint.